# Why should I version control all files generated by Xtext/Xtend?

Tags: xtext, xtend

The Xtext/Xtend examples do not exclude the generated files form version control (in `.gitignore`). This makes commits huge and sometimes hard to merge.

What is the reason for adding all generated files to version control?

Answer (score 2):

In the log files, log entries and stack traces refer to the generated `.java` files (not the `.xtend` files). Therefore it is much easier to investigate problems in test/production systems if the generated `.java` files are easily accessible for each version of your application.

*(Side note: I never commit the generated files because of the problems you mentioned - but I don't have any production system in Xtend where the quick tracing of problems would be important.)*